# Preventing user from accessing parent folders

Tags: shell, ssh, permissions, chmod

I have a user who I only want to be able to access `/var/www/ucp/` (his home directory). I have executed the following command on the / directory, the `/var/` directory and the `/var/www/` directory: `chmod o-rwx ~`

However, when I connect to this user via SSH, they can still navigate out of the `/var/www/ucp/` directory. I do not want them to be able to access any other directory at all, but I do want them to have full access to everything inside `/var/www/ucp/`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply give read and execute access to /var/www/ and read write and execute access to ucp

`cd /var/www/
chmod 777 ucp 
cd ../../
chmod 555 /var`

or even complicated  by making execute access to /var/www but in this case you have to make sure that user will type a complete path to reach at ucp

`cd /var/www
chmod 777 ucp
cd ../../
chmod 111 /var`

Note:- 777 are subjected to your policy i mean the permission what you to give that dir "UCP" can be replace by 777